# pasar datos de un input a un src

Tags: javascript, html

al poner algo en `data=` en la etiqueta `img`, te convierte a código de barras.

como hago que lo que tenga el **`input`** se pase a ese data?

hice un `script` pero no tengo ni idea de como pasarlo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
 
<body>
 <table>
  <div id="h">
 <tr>
  <td style='padding:10px; text-align:center; font-size:15px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica;'>
   <br/>
  </td>
  <td>
   <label>Ingrese el documento que desea convertir</label>
            <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto">
   <img src='https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=&code=Code128&multiplebarcodes=false&translate-esc=false&unit=Fit&dpi=96&imagetype=Gif&rotation=0&color=%23000000&bgcolor=%23ffffff&qunit=Mm&quiet=0' alt='Barcode Generator TEC-IT'/>
   <button onclick="convertir()">convertir</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </div>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function convertir() {
   alert("Hello World!");
   var conv = document.getelementbyid('texto').value;

  }
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: que tal si cambias el `getelementbyid` por [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Como dice Jack, JavaScript es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es escribir bien la propiedad **getElementById**, y con eso tomara el valor de tu input.

Lo que después necesitas hacer es asignarle un id o una clase a tu imagen para poder asignarle un nuevo atributo src al dar click en el boton.

Y por ultimo solo concaternarle el valor de tu input al valor del src que le vas a dar a la imagen, por ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <div id="h">
            <tr>
                <td style='padding:10px; text-align:center; font-size:15px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica;'>
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Ingrese el documento que desea convertir</label>
                    <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto">
                    <img id="myImg" src="https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=&code=Code128&multiplebarcodes=false&translate-esc=false&unit=Fit&dpi=96&imagetype=Gif&rotation=0&color=%23000000&bgcolor=%23ffffff&qunit=Mm&quiet=0" alt='Barcode Generator TEC-IT' />
                    <button onclick="convertir()">convertir</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function convertir() {
            var conv = document.getElementById('texto').value;
            var src = document.getElementById("myImg").src = "https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=" + conv + "&code=Code128&multiplebarcodes=false&translate-esc=false&unit=Fit&dpi=96&imagetype=Gif&rotation=0&color=%23000000&bgcolor=%23ffffff&qunit=Mm&quiet=0";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero y te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que acceder al atributo **`SRC`** de la imagen , que hice: agregue un id a la imagen para poder acceder al **`src`** de esta y luego lo cambie.

Tenias mal el **getelementbyid**, cambien la **funcion** por un evento **click** en el botón.

Revisa el snippet

```js
$("#btnConvert").click(function(){
   var conv = document.getElementById('texto').value;
    console.log(conv);
    $("#srcImg").attr("src","https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data="+conv+"&code=Code128&multiplebarcodes=false&translate-esc=false&unit=Fit&dpi=96&imagetype=Gif&rotation=0&color=%23000000&bgcolor=%23ffffff&qunit=Mm&quiet=0");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
 
<body>
 <table>
  <div id="h">
 <tr>
  <td style='padding:10px; text-align:center; font-size:15px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica;'>
   <br/>
  </td>
  <td>
   <label>Ingrese el documento que desea convertir</label>
            <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto">
            <br>
   <img src='https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=&code=Code128&multiplebarcodes=false&translate-esc=false&unit=Fit&dpi=96&imagetype=Gif&rotation=0&color=%23000000&bgcolor=%23ffffff&qunit=Mm&quiet=0' id="srcImg" alt='Barcode Generator TEC-IT'/>
   <button id="btnConvert">convertir</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </div>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```